# Are there any packages for knitting?

Tags: packages, fun, big-list

So I showed my girlfriend the [braids](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/the-braids-package/) package, and she asked if their are any packages for knitting patterns. I couldn't find any on ctan with a quick search, so I thought I'd ask here. Are their any packages for knitting or related disciplines?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/knitting?lang=en ?

Comment: Or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/knittingpattern?

Comment: Very nice tutorial about knittingpattern https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Knitting_patterns

Comment: It would be great if someone would write these up with a short description so I could accept an answer.

Comment: @Canageek You can sum up what you fouond out as well ;-)